# How could I order by sum, within a DataFrame in PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Analogously to:

```
order_items.groupBy("order_item_order_id").count().orderBy(desc("count")).show()
```

I have tried:

```
order_items.groupBy("order_item_order_id").sum("order_item_subtotal").orderBy(desc("sum")).show()
```

but this gives an error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o501.sort.
>   : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'sum' given input columns order_item_order_id, SUM(order_item_subtotal#429);

I have also tried:

```
order_items.groupBy("order_item_order_id").sum("order_item_subtotal").orderBy(desc("SUM(order_item_subtotal)")).show()
```

but I get the same error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o512.sort.
>   : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'SUM(order_item_subtotal)' given input columns order_item_order_id, SUM(order_item_subtotal#429);

I get the right result when executing:

```
order_items.groupBy("order_item_order_id").sum("order_item_subtotal").orderBy(desc("SUM(order_item_subtotal#429)")).show()
```

but this was done *a posteriori*, after having seen the number that Spark appends to the sum column name, i.e. **#429**.

Is there a way to get the same result but *a priori*, without knowing which number will be appended?

Answer (score 12):

You should use aliases for your columns:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

order_items.groupBy("order_item_order_id")\
           .agg(func.sum("order_item_subtotal")\
                .alias("sum_column_name"))\
           .orderBy("sum_column_name")
```

Comment: Thank you. To get also the column "order_item_order_id" (analogously to the output in the case with the count function), I have added this as an argument to the agg function: 
`order_items.groupBy("order_item_order_id")\
           .agg(order_items["order_item_order_id"],\
                   func.sum("order_item_subtotal")\
                      .alias("sum_column_name"))\
           .orderBy("sum_column_name")`
 
Nevertheless, I wonder if there is a simpler way to get the same result, as in the example for count.

Comment: You don't need to complicate things, just use the code provided:
`order_items.groupBy("order_item_order_id").agg(func.sum("order_item_subtotal").alias("sum_column_name")).orderBy("sum_column_name")` I have tested it and it works.

Comment: Your code gives as output only the column "sum_column_name" and I also need the column "order_item_order_id". That is the reason I had to add this column inside the agg: `order_items.groupBy("order_item_order_id").agg(order_items["order_item_order_id"], func.sum("order_item_subtotal").‌alias("sum_column_name")).orderBy("sum_column_name")`

Comment: Oh I see, you're right about that
Please consider using `cube` if you need multiple levels of aggregation with different aggregation functions. For example, you could write:
`order_items.cube('order_item_order_id', 'some_other_column').agg({'order_item_subtotal': 'sum', '*': 'count'})`

Comment: For completion, If you want to do an ascending sort, you can add ```ascending=True``` in orderBy term like this:  ```.orderBy("sum_column_name",ascending=True)```